# SQL Join over three tables

Tags: sql, join

I have 3 SQL-Tables:

customers:

```
id
name
name2
```

books:

```
id
title
cID (contains the id of the customer)
```

sales:

```
id
value
bID (contains the id of the book)
```

How can I join the 3 tables to have an result like this?

```
Customer name
Customer name 2
Book title
Sales value
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, that will make easier for us to help you.

Comment: I am not downvoting you but if this is your schema, then you should be aware that you should put the customer ID on the sale record, not on the book record, unless you are only going to sell each book to one person!

Answer (score 1):

Thus:

```
select 
  c.name as "Customer name", 
  c.name2 as "Customer name 2", 
  b.title as "Book title", 
  s.value as "Sales value"
from 
  customers c 
  inner join books b on b.cID = c.id
  inner join sales s on s.bID = b.id
```

If your database doesn't support ANSI SQL notions of "put quotes around column aliases to allow them to have spaces", use the relevant character your database does normally use

Answer (score 0):

```
Select c.name, c.name2, b.title, s.value from customers c 
left join books b on c.id = b.cID
left join sales s on b.id = b.bID
```